# Which method is appropriate for modelling temperature data and other variables of electricity generation

Tags: regression

I Have large data set  values of generated temperature on PV and solar(measured hourly for one year). I am looking to see the trend as well as relation between the temperature and other independent variables . What kind of regression analysis is suitable for such a situation?
In one model, I am interested to see temperature as dependent variable.
In second model, I would like to see power genrated as dependent variable and temperature and other associated variables as independent variables.
Which regression method is useful?
I have used Mathlab. But not very clear. any othwr software is useful for such analysis.

Answer (score 1):

When we talk about the power generated, then you have non-negative values (but possibly sometimes exactly zero or so close to it that it might just as well be the same thing). For temperature, it is in theory the same thing (i.e. temperatures will always be above the absolute zero), but the measured temperatures may be so far away from the absolute zero that they might just as well be unbounded values. So, normal error terms might be fine for the temperature, but not for the power generated (there perhaps a log-normal, or some classical time-to-event distribution such as Weibull may be more appropriate).

Clearly there is some cyclic nature (i.e. night-time hours should have no generation of energy, unless a diesel-generator was run due to an extremely high feed-in-tariff) so time-series methods seem like one option. You would also want to account for (depending on the world) some monthly effects (presumably you can find out when sunrise and sunset were and what the position of the sun means for the angle at which the sun comes onto the panels - you might want to look at how far off from straight on the angle was) and perhaps effects of weather (e.g. cloud cover). If you do not use standard time-series methods, then random effects models that account for the correlation between measurements from the same site  (assuming you have data from multiple sites) and within the site on adjacent hours/days may be an option.

There are many software packages that should be suitable for analyzing these data (e.g. R). I have no experience with Matlab.